# CompareTo LinkedList greatest volume java

Tags: java

I file read a file with width height and length to a linked list of objects and now I have to find which object from the linked list has the greatest and smallest volume. I tried doing this for the greatest method but I get this error: *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Double cannot be cast to class Box (java.lang.Double is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; Box is in unnamed module of loader 'app').* Which I think it's because what I am comparing is wrong I am not sure what to compare. And this does have to be done with the compareTo method I have

UPDATE: I have change the compares to head and head.next and now it is printing the correct volume but it is printing null after it how can I remove that. And for the smaller method it is printing an extra volume line when it's only supposed to be one and a nullpointerexception message

```
static void largestBox(Box head){
     while(head != null){
        if (head.next.compareTo(head) > 0){
            head = head.next;
            System.out.println(head.next);
        }
        head = head.next;
    }

}
    class Box {
      private double width, height, length;
      public Box next;

    Box(double w, double h, double l){
        width=w;
        height=h;
        length=l;
    }

    double getVolume(){
       return width*height*length;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object o){    
      double vol1 = this.getVolume();
      double vol2 = ((Box)o).getVolume();
      if (vol1>vol2)
        return 1;
      else if (vol1<vol2)
         return -1;
      else
        return 0;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

> `if(head.next.compareTo(bigVolume) > 0)`

You are trying to compare a `Box` (`head.next`) to a `double` (`bigVolume`). This line should instead look like `if (head.next.compareTo(head))`, which will let you compare boxes instead of a volume and a Box. This should get you on the right track, but I will warn you I see other issues with your code.

Comment: do you mean issues outside of the largestVolume method?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
double bigVolume = head.getVolume();
```

To:

```
Box biggestBox = head;
```

And change

```
if (head.next.compareTo(bigVolume) > 0) {
```

To

```
if (head.next.compareTo(biggestBox) > 0) {
```

---

There's another bug in your code. Change:

```
while (head != null) {
```

to:

```
while (head.next != null) {
```

Also, you're always printing `System.out.println(head);` not matter what is the biggest box. Change it to `System.out.println(biggestBox);`

Comment: I have to use the compareto method I have

Comment: @sdfw3 ah. See edits.

Comment: the wrong box is printing its not the one with the big volume and after this shows up Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Box.compareTo(Object)" because "<parameter1>.next" is null

Comment: @sdfw3  change `while(head != null){` to `while(head.next != null){` Also, you probably want a `toString()` method in your `Box` class that displays its dimensions and volume.

Comment: I don't get an error now but still the wrong one is printing

Comment: Maybe change `System.out.println(head);` to `System.out.println(biggestBox);`?

Comment: I just update the code to it working now and printing the correct one but it is printing null under it any idea why

Comment: I don't know what "under it" means, but I expect your `largestBox` method should have a return type of `Box` (not `void`) and should `return biggestBox;` (and delete the `System.out.println()` too - that's only debug info, not part of the actual solution)

Comment: its a void cause I am finding it and just printing it not returning anything. I am not using biggestBox anymore just head and head.next it is printing W: 101.0 H: 105.0 L: 18.0 Vol: 190890.0 
null

Comment: its the correct line but then it just says null under that line